# wp_editor responsive?

Tags: editor, responsive

I am calling `<?php wp_editor( '' , 'movie_description-'.$num, array('textarea_name' => 'url[]', 'raw' => true ));?>` but I want it to be responsive so that it doesn't overflow outside of the container. The parent container has a set width, but the content area extends outside of that and the tinymce buttons are not visible. Is there a simple way to make the editor responsive?